# emacs neotree go to directory when using helm projectile

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

How can I make it such that whenever I do `helm-projectile-find-file`, neotree will jump to that directory?

Answer (score 1):

you could add an advice to helm-projectile-find-file that it runs neotree-find once it's done.

Something like this:

```
(defadvice helm-projectile-find-file (after helm-projectile-find-file activate)
  (neotree-dir default-directory))
```

Hope this helps